# How do I query my API to format results so that Typeahead can use it?

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, json, typeahead.js

Typeahead needs my JSON results to look something like this:

```
Array [
{"id": "5001", "email": "me@myself.com"},
{"id": "5002", "email": "you@yourself.org"},
{"id": "5003", "email": "them@anywhere.net"},
{"id": "5004", "email": "nobody@home.us"},
{"id": "5005", "email": "anyone@anytime.info"}, ...];
```

But when I use this query:

```
    $sth = $this->pdo()->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM advocates ;"
    );
    $result = $sth->execute();
    if( $result && $sth->rowCount() > 0 ) {
        while($row=$sth->fetch()) {
            $alladv_emails['id'] = $row['id'];
            $alladv_emails['email'] = $row['emailAddress'];
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($alladv_emails);
```

I only get one result like this:

```
Array ( [value] => cmyles97@yahoo.com [data] => 53930344 )
```

How can I redesign my query to format my JSON like what is expected?

Also, obviously I want to get more than 1 result. I think it is overwriting the array each time, which is why I get only 1 result. But, when I try to add a qualifying array number, it complicates the JSON even more.

I tried this:

```
        $alladv_emails[0]['id'] = $row['id'];
        $alladv_emails[0]['email'] = $row['emailAddress'];
```

and it comes out looking like this, and STILL only returned 1 row:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => cmyles97@yahoo.com [data] => 53930344 ) )
```

Originally I was going to use this:

```
            $alladv_emails[$row['id']] = $row['emailAddress'];
```

But then, I get this type of result, but I do get all 17000 results, just not in the format I want.

```
Array ( [40891510] => obfuscate@aol.com [40891511] => obfuscate@nobleharbor.com [40891512] => obfuscate@rochester.rr.com [40891513] => obfuscate@hotmail.com ...
```

NEW INFORMATION:

I added the following function after my last php query:

```
    $emailarray = array();
    $subarray = array();
    foreach ($session->getAllEmails() as $key => $val){
        $subarray = array('id' => $key, 'email' => $val);
        array_push($emailarray,$subarray);
    }
```

...and now I get something that is VERY close to what I need:

```
    Array 
( [0] => Array 
    ( [id] => 40891510 
    [email] => obfuscate@aol.com ) 
[1] => Array 
    ( [id] => 40891511 
    [email] => obfuscate@nobleharbor.com ) 
[2] => Array (
    [id] => 40891512 
    [email] => obfuscate@rochester.rr.com )
...
```

Almost there. It still does not work right in typeahead.

Comment: `$alladv_emails['id'][] = $row['id'];` Would push to the next index. `$alladv_emails['id'] = $row['id'];` just keeps overwriting `$alladv_emails['id']`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I had not thought of placing the open braces after the ['id']. Let me try that out.

Comment: OK I tried it, and it does not work. What I get when I do that is an array composed of an array of all the IDs: "Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => 40891510 [1] => 40891511 [2] => 40891512 [3] => 40891513 ....." etc.

Comment: It looks like you did `$alladv_emails[] = $row['id'];` and not `$alladv_emails['id'][] = $row['id'];` like I suggested. Also, you'll need to do it for `$alladv_emails['email'][] = $row['emailAddress'];`